# Can we navigate to different pages inside within loop in capybara/siteprism?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, site-prism

My code is like this:

```
my_array.each do |element|
  within element do
    some_element.click         #it will take me to next page
    some_other_element.click   #it will take me to previous page for next iteration
  end
end
```

In siteprism page it is like this:

```
elements :array, 'ul.class li'
```

When I run, its executing successfully for the first iteration, but in second iteration its throwing error like `cache element not available`

If I navigate to different pages then i loose the scope of `my_array` elements??

Can anyone help me with this...??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > If I navigate to different pages then i loose the scope of array elements??

Yes, the scope has changed.

The reason it fails is because the elements that are on the page when the loop first runs are not present on the second page even though it may look like they are - they are different elements. Because you have moved page you need to get the elements again from scratch.

On how to make it work...

There seem to be a number of issues with the code in the question. The first is that the fact you are
using a `within` block in the context of an element instead of a section. The first thing I'd do (not
being able to see your code) is to replace your `elements` with `sections`, and I'd model whatever the
`li` is as a section. Eg:

```
class MySection < SitePrism::Section
  element :some_element, "#some-element"
  element :some_other_element, "#some_other_element"
end
```

Then I'd add model the `li` elements of the `ul` as a collection of sections in a page, eg:

```
class MyPage < SitePrism::Page
  sections :list_items, MySection, 'ul.class li'
end
```

To get around the scoping issue, I'd have something like the following:

```
@my_page = MyPage.new

number_of_list_items = @my_page.list_items.size

number_of_list_items.times do |list_item_position|
  MyPage.new.list_items[list_item_position].some_element.click
  MyPage.new.list_items[list_item_position].some_other_element.click
end
```

Comment: So, is there any way to do the above operation using siteprism?

Comment: Updated answer to show how I'd do it... I hope I've understood your code correctly and the problem you're trying to solve!

Comment: wow!!Thanks Nat...I didnt got the idea of sections for li elements...its amazing...Thanks